# Changing background color of glyphicon in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the background color of a glyphicon upon hover/focus without success in my banner.Below is a code snippet for the 2 glyphicons i.e. **glyphicon-user** and **glyphicon-login**. The background changes to white even though I've set another color in the css.

**1.html**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-offset-4 col-md-4">
  <a id="logo" href="#"> <img src="../static/images/logo_small.png" data-medium="../static/images/logo_medium.png" data-large="../static/images/logo_large.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li><a class="custom-white" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a class="custom-white" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**2.css**

```
.custom-white { color:#fff;}

.custom-white:hover, 
.custom-white:active,
.custom-white:focus {background-color: yellow;}
```

Comment: I like to know, what you have to change either the background color of the menu or color of the glyphicons inside the menu. Can you pls clear on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your CSS to this:

```
.nav>li>a.custom-white:hover, 
.nav>li>a.custom-white:active,
.nav>li>a.custom-white:focus {background-color: yellow;}
```

See [this demo](http://www.bootply.com/jUwQpq5epy)

HTH,
-Ted

Answer (score 1):

add `!important` after the attribute's value

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mirohristov/FzPEj/247/)

```
.custom-white:hover, 
.custom-white:active,
.custom-white:focus {background-color: yellow !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the "!important" css feature to override bootstrap's css. For example,

`.custom-white:hover,
.custom-white:active,
.custome-white:focus 
 {background-color: yellow !important;}`

Otherwise, the browser will compile bootsrap's default first. Hope that works!

Comment: Hmm... I thought that the custom css is loaded after the bootstrap css, hence the **!important** keyword is not required?  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/css/custom_bootstrap.css">`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead,
Just update your nav css lines

```
.nav>li>a:hover, 
.nav>li>a:active,
.nav>li>a:focus {background-color: yellow;}
```