# How to make bootstrap carousel with controls below

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

[So this is what I need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOGvI.png)

How can I put the controls ( < and > ) below the carousel(like in the picture) give them a background-color?

I try to modify the bootstrap carousel example , link : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Here you've to provide some code (at least what you've tried so far). We're here to help, not to provide free code.

Comment: Where can I upload my code? Tell me please a good online editor. And I didn't upload my code because I use the bootstrap example carousel, link : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel . All I want to do is to have the controls unde the slide and put them a background-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Source :  [Bootstrap Carousel-W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp) )
Try this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="img_chania.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_chania2.jpg" alt="Chania" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="img_flower2.jpg" alt="Flower" width="460" height="345">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The   **<**  and **>** are here called **Glyphicon**  .  `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left` for **<** and `glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right` for **>** . There are many more **Glyphicon** symbols . Here are some examples : [Bootstrap Glyphicon - W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_glyphs.asp)

Are you looking for background colors for glyphicons ? see this question :
[Changing backgound color of glyphicon in Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612349/changing-backgound-color-of-glyphicon-in-bootstrap)

You can also download templates with built-in carousel including **<** and **>** signs . Here is an [example](http://demo.evatheme.com/html/white/image_slider/index.html)

Comment: @Mihai C
Are looking for background color for Glyphicon s ?
then see this questions :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28612349/changing-backgound-color-of-glyphicon-in-bootstrap

Comment: I try to move the glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left and glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right like in this example https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOGvI.png . I want them to be under the image slider in the left part. Then , I want to give them a background-color like in the picture (that blue color)